# Kubernetes nginx ingress: Server-side HTTPS enforcement through redirect

Tags: kubernetes, redirect, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, nginx-location

I've setup my ingress-controller in aws EKS. I've added `cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"` for my ingress. The problem is every time the backend sends **307** redirect in `http`. The ingress controller sends same `http` to frontend, causing `Mixed Block` error from the browser.

Here is my sample ingress:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - kube.example.com
    secretName: kube-tls
  rules:
  - host: kube.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /api/v1/
        backend:
          service:
            name: service-nodeport
            port:
              number: 8000
```

According to the documentation, it should have redirect to https by default ([link](https://docs.giantswarm.io/advanced/ingress/configuration/#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect)). Is it different for 307 redirect?

### Additional Details:

**Installing nginx ingress controller**

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.0.2/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy.yaml
```

**Installing cert-manager**

```
kubectl apply --validate=false -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v0.16.1/cert-manager.yaml
```

setting up clusterissuers and certificate issuing is done as per the documentation

**Describe Ingress**

```
Name:             example-nginx-ingress
Namespace:        dev
Address:          a629a[MASKED]-a2f82eec00a54190.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
TLS:
  kube-tls terminates kube.example.com
Rules:
  Host                 Path  Backends
  ----                 ----  --------
  kube.example.com  
                       /api/v1/   svc-nodeport:8000 (192.168.7.44:8001)
                       /          webapp-nodeport:80 (192.168.4.90:80)
Annotations:           cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
                       kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
Events:                <none>
```

**Deployment and service are setup as basic**

`svc-nodeport` is backed by gunicorn (i.e. a python webserver) container and `webapp-nodeport` is backed by nginx container.

#### Alternative way I thought

I tried to add location snippet in my ingress, to actually remove the trailing slash (/) from request. But It didn't worked. You can help me on this too.

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/location-snippet: |
      location = /api/v1/ {
        rewrite api/v1/$1 ^api/v1/(.*)/$ break;
        }
```

Comment: I tried to test your configuration but I get [standard 308 redirection which is expected](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect) (with other service as the backend). Could you please share some details - how did you install NGINX Ingress controller and Let's Encrypt? Could you please paste output from the `kubectl describe ing {your-ingress}`? Could you share your service and deployments files?

Comment: @MikolajS.. Here you go. I've added additional details

Comment: Everything looks good... Could you please do "Check the Ingress Controller Logs" (from [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/troubleshooting/) site) and see if there is something interesting? Also, could you do "Check the Nginx Configuration" from the same side and check if there are configs related to the 307 error?

Comment: Nothing much in logs. It's not an error actually. It a redirect response from application. But its in http (while browser expects redirects in https).

Comment: Which Kubernetes version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#hsts). Try set `hsts` to false.

Comment: I've tried adding annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/hsts: "false"`, but it didn't fixed the issue